# 'package not found error' while installing pytorch on Windows Anaconda python

Tags: windows-10, anaconda, python-3.5, pytorch, 32-bit

I have installed anaconda python 3.5.5 and willing to install pytorch. I tried many commands supporting this but landed into the ‘package not found error’.,yes i had make sure that i’m running the prompt as adminstrator. can i have any better solutions [image]

Answer (score 0):

you could use pip to install pytorch and the command can be found at the official site.

```
http://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu80/torch-0.4.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

or you could paste this site **(make sure you have chosen the right version you need)** to a download tool and use

```
pip install x:\your_download_path\torch-0.4.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

to install it

Comment: tried max commands that supports installation ,did not worked.

Comment: I just renew my answer. you could try it

Answer (score 0):

Installing Python packages in windows using Anaconda has requires you to specify the source from where the package has to be installed.

You can do: `conda install -c peterjc123 pytorch` to install PyTorch using Anaconda.

Comment: Tried this command along with its supporting commands,did not worked.Is there any specific path defined for this.

Answer (score 0):

It is bit difficult to install pytorch on windows10 (32bit) as many of the software packages supporting 'machine learning' are written with 64bit processors. one can try it with updating the conda package with 'conda update --all', if this does not works and still gives the same error then login to 'https://anaconda.org' and use the search bar for the alternative channels supporting the installation of pytorch on 32bit processor,this worked for me.